# beginning symbol of php scripts

Tags: php

I re-installed and upgrade my ubuntu version from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 then I installed apache2 and php.
The problem is that I have php scripts that begins with `<?` but now these scripts only work if I change `<?` to `<?php`. How can I make that php work with `<?`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the option [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) to `1` (true) in your php.ini and it should work fine.

Comment: For more fine-grained control, you can also set it per-site using [`php_flag` or `php_admin_flag`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) in your apache config..

Comment: Thank you!!! I have `php 5.5.3`, in my case, The value to set is `short_open_tag = On` Then restart apache2